# Binding constantly updated string with textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I wish to bind a String with a textbox. The string is constantly being updated in a thread:

```
String inputread;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string InputRead
    {
        get { return inputread; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(inputread, value) == true) return;
            inputread = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.inputread));
        }


    }
    void threadFunc()
    {
        try
        {
            while (threadRunning)
            {
                plc.Read();
                InputRead =plc.InputImage[1].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(InputRead);
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
        }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Later on the Binding declaration:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("InputRead");
bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(newtextbox, TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
```

I understand that part of the problem why this is not working (the textbox is completely empty) is because I do not refresh it every time the thread runs.  How do I do it? Also I suspect the Binding declaration is flawed I am not sure how.

I read the MSDN article about data binding, it helped me get this far.
I googled it that is how i got this far, also with the help of Stackoverflow earlier, still no success.

**EDIT:**  I edited the code a bit, still textbox is empty (not even 0). I am using wpf! If it is easier, could someone guide me to use dispatcher.invoke ?

Thank you!

Comment: What is UI framework you are using? `Winforms`, `WPF`

Comment: wpf, sorry for not saying that

Comment: _could someone guide me to use dispatcher.invoke_ Wpf is cross-thread safe. Raised `PropertyChanged` event will be marshalled back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

In `threadFunc()` function, you set the value directly to `inputread` (lower case), it's a field and have no call to `OnPropertyChanged`.
You can change the code in `threadFunc()` to `InputRead=plc.InputImage[1].ToString();`
I hope it works for you.

Comment: I think I found problem. Maybe you forget to set the DataContext. You bind to 'InputRead', but you don't tell the compiler where is 'InputRead'.
So, add this line in binding declaration may help.
DataContext = new <Your class contain InputRead>();

Answer (score 0):

You need create a property and bind `TextBox` to the property

```
private string _Inputed;
public string Inputed
{
    get { return _Inputed; }
    set 
    {
        if(Equals(_Inputed, value) == true) return;
        _Inputed = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Inputed));
    }
}

void threadFunc()
{
    try
    {
        while (threadRunning)
        {
            plc.Read();
            this.Inputed = plc.InputImage[1].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Inputed}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! How do i bind the textbox to the property? Is my solution not good? I will edit the original question to show where i am at.